# display on a listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

This is an Intent from another class, The name **product** contains data from sqlite database.

my problem is i want to display the information on the ListView but i do not know how to do it.

```
Intent updateCustomerIntent = getIntent();
         String product = updateCustomerIntent.getStringExtra("product");
         Log.d("checking........", product);
```

i have tried this

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, product);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

but it gives me errors

I will appriciate your help.

Comment: Please add which errors you get.

Comment: thanx i got the right answer Tom :)

Comment: Sure, but it will be useful for other users to find it in the future, in case they have the same problem as you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it like this :

```
String[] values = new String[] { product };

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```